# RF receivers without clock

Tags: electrical-engineering

Most of the RF receivers have a clock for synchronization. Are there RF receivers which do not need clock? If yes,  how do they work?

Comment: [Detector radio receivers](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Electronic/amfmdet.html), for an example.

Comment: There is a whole raft of selfclocking communication protocols. See [line code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_code) and [Manchester code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code)

Comment: All RF Rx's need a clock unless you are old enough to remember the pickle jar AM crystal detector and earbud radio that had a high Q coil with a sliding tap, cat's whisker diode and crystal esrbud for AM band.   Note that baseband is not RF per se.

Answer (score 1):

RF receivers generally need to receive signal over a known and narrow frequency range.  As such, they need some mechanism to accomplish this frequency selection.

Some methods of frequency selection utilize a signal at a known frequency, which you could possibly call a "clock", although I think that's stretching the term a bit.

For example, a basic AM radio receiver can be made selective by utilizing the narrow passband of a LC filter (inductor and capacitor working together).  This is exactly how early AM radios worked.  Then the *super-heterodyne* method came along, which does use a specific synthesized frequency to allow for a more selective overall filter.

If you mean by "clock" that the receiver needs to know absolute time, then no, the statement *"most RF receivers have a clock for synchronization"* is just nonsense.  Some higher level systems may need to know the time for other reasons, but simply receiving and demodulating the RF is not one of them.

You could conceive of higher level transmission protocols that might, for example, use frequency-hopping on a known schedule.  In that case, the receiver might use a clock.

GPS decoding ultimately requires synchronization, but the modulation scheme is designed so that this synchronization can be derived from watching the RF signals for long enough.  Eventually finding position requires knowing the time very precisely, but that's at a higher level above the RF receivers.